# why div background does not contain inner element unless floated?

Tags: css, browser, html

I have a block of html like this. Judging by the background color of the divs, the outer div is not containing the inner div, unless I remove "float:left" from the inner div, or add "float:left" to the outer div. Why is that? http://jsbin.com/ihiqoz/2/edit

```
<div style="width:900px; background-color:#1EFF1E">
    <p>outside</p>
    <div style="float:left; width: 25%; background-color:#BD78C8">
        <p>inside</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to clear your float:

```
<div style="width:900px; background-color:#1EFF1E">
    <p>outside</p>
    <div style="float:left; width: 25%; background-color:#BD78C8">
        <p>inside</p>
    </div>
    <div style="clear: left;"></div>
</div>
```

Floating elements break out of the layout, so your div doesn't get considered by the elements around it. The `clear` css property forces an element to move after the last floating element, so when you place an empty div below your floating element by giving it the `clear` style, the outer div will stretch to contain it.

Comment: You don't have to clear it, just adding the BR is enough for background to stretch to the bottom.

Comment: A `<br>` won't work. It will only stretch the green div by one `line-height`. It won't stretch it to contain the floating div.

Answer (score 2):

@ray; if you have `float` in your child element so you have to `clear` it's `parent` so just write `overflow:hidden` in it's parent div to `clear` it.

For Example:

```
<div style="width:900px; background-color:#1EFF1E; overflow:hidden">
    <p>outside</p>
    <div style="float:left; width: 25%; background-color:#BD78C8">
        <p>inside</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

read this article for more http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html

Answer (score -1):

You can also add `<BR>` at the end of the div, after the floated one.

Edit: You need to clear the div.

Comment: A `<br>` won't work. It will only stretch the green div by one `line-height`. It won't stretch it to contain the floating div.